# JSON parsing error when trying to update AWS stepfunction from aws cli

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli, aws-step-functions

I'm trying to update an existing AWS stepfunction with the aws cli
First, I'm doing :

```
    aws stepfunctions update-state-machine --generate-cli-skeleton
```

to create a JSON file skeleton, then I updated it with the stepfunction details (arn, role) and the definition.

Example (replaced actual arm and role)

```
{
    "stateMachineArn": "arn:aws:states:us-west-2:xxx .... xxx",
    "definition": "{
  "Comment": "A TEST example of the Amazon States Language using Pass states",
  "StartAt": "Hello",
  "States": {
    "Hello": {
      "Type": "Pass",
      "Result": "Hello",
      "Next": "World"
    },
    "World": {
      "Type": "Pass",
      "Result": "World",
      "End": true
    }
  }
}",
    "roleArn": "iam_role"
}
```

Then I'm trying

```
aws stepfunctions update-state-machine --cli-input-json file://C:\Users\nufardo\Desktop\test.json
```

but getting this error:

```
Error parsing parameter 'cli-input-json': Invalid JSON: Invalid control character at: line 3 column 21 (char 112)
```

The description is copy-paste from aws itself, so I expect it to be good.
the json file is in UTF8
Looking on some aws examples with json I don't see them using escape characters for quotes or parenthesis so I have no clue why this isnt working...

And (unfortunately) i'm using windows

Thanks for anyone who tries to help!

Comment: I think you need to escape the quotes inside the "definition".

Comment: Thanks, this works when the entire json is in one line, but doesn't work when I write it multi line